# Profiling Webworkers in Firefox

Tags: performance, firefox, profiling, web-worker

I am trying to profile a Javascript app with Firefox Quantum. The part that I am most interested in runs inside webworkers. I am not sure if I am doing everything correctly, but I cannot find a way to get any useful data with the built in profiler. All I can see is this:

[image]

Is there a hidden feature that can help me look inside the webworker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further looking into this I came to the conclusion that Firefox does not support runtime analysis for web workers at the moment. I will have stick with Chrome for profiling our app.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else finding this in the future: https://profiler.firefox.com/ is able to profile Web Workers.

You need to open the `Resources` drop-down and choose `Thread: DOM Worker`.